# Where can I find the frameworks blade implementation?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to find where Laravel implements the default blade tags, for example;

```
@for
@endfor
@lang
```

I want to extend `@lang` but would like to see the underlining code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer while typing this question out. They are implemented here

```
Concerns\CompilesAuthorizations,
Concerns\CompilesComments,
Concerns\CompilesComponents,
Concerns\CompilesConditionals,
Concerns\CompilesEchos,
Concerns\CompilesIncludes,
Concerns\CompilesInjections,
Concerns\CompilesJson,
Concerns\CompilesLayouts,
Concerns\CompilesLoops,
Concerns\CompilesRawPhp,
Concerns\CompilesStacks,
Concerns\CompilesTranslations;
```

Found at `Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler`